# How to import "kCurrentProcess" and other items from "ApplicationServices Enumerations"?

Tags: objective-c

I have an Objective-C XCode project open that I originally wrote back in 2018 (about 4 years ago as of the time of this posting).

At that time, the project built with no issues. Now, building the project produces a few errors, including:

- `Use of undeclared identifier 'kCurrentProcess'`
- `Use of undeclared identifier 'kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication'`
- `Implicit declaration of function 'TransformProcessType' is invalid in C99`

A [Google search for "kCurrentProcess"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22kcurrentprocess%22&nfpr=1) turns up little apart from [a rather sparse Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1501096-anonymous/kcurrentprocess?language=objc), whose entire body consists of the following:

> **Declaration**
>
> kCurrentProcess = 2

The hierarchy of that doc page does indicate that `kCurrentProcess` is a part of something called "ApplicationServices Enumerations", but that's all -- no information on what .h file needs to be imported.

I suppose I could get my program to build by adding my own declaration of kCurrentProcess, like:

```
#define kCurrentProcess 2
```

I'd rather import the actual declaration, though.

What do I need to `#import` in order to pick up the declarations for these "ApplicationServices Enumerations" items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some experimentation, it appears that the requisite import is:

```
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
```

Adding that to my own .h file corresponding to the .m file where the build errors were occurring resolved the issue for my project.